# Implement "docker rmi" in Python Docker API

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I want to have the Python equivalent of the below command:

```sh
docker rmi $(docker images -q -a)
```

The `remove` method is equivalent to `rmi` but how about the `-q` and `-a` options?

Comment: Did you read the Docker docs to see what those flags to the images command mean? The Python library docs to see what parameters the equivalent method accepts?

Comment: yes, @jonrsharpe. -a means show all images and -q means show only image id.

Comment: Tried this:
for image in dclient.images.list():
        print("Image: ", image.id)

Comment: And *does* that give you all the image ids? I assume you're talking about https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.list, where it seems clear what the equivalent of `-a` would be.

Comment: Yea, I had doubt about -q but anyway that can be get from image attributes. But still I could not get the image name from the object. When i print the object i get Image:  <Image: 'python:3.6'>.

Comment: That's an [Image object](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#image-objects), so it seems to be working fine. What's the *problem*?

Comment: i tried tags attribute and got that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Below will work fine:

```
for image in client.images.list():
        print("Image: ", image.tags)
        client.images.remove(image=tag, force=True)
```

Comment: I find that `client.images.remove(image.id, force=True)` works.